# window.location.assign() not implemented in Jest JSDom

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs, sinon

I have the function

```
 window.location.assign(url)
```

which does not exist in jsdom... so raising an error in my test

Someone mention the possibility to stub this function ( using Sinon)
[see jsdom issue](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2112)

```
 sinon.stub(window.location, 'assign');
 expect(window.location.assign).to.have.been.calledWith(url);
```

How can I replicate it using Jest ? ( since it does not exist , I cannot use spies... it has to be mocked )

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could provide your custom implementation

```
jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign').mockImplementation(url => console.log(url))
```

Comment: thanks @Yury ... got it right. I updated the title of the question to reflect correctly the issue...

Comment: This complained about assign being readonly. Following solution worked for me:
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    writable: true,
    value: { assign: jest.fn() }
  });